# How to prevent implicit conversion to bool in conditions?

Tags: typescript2.0

For example if I do this in Haxe:

```
var a=33;
if(a)
   // do something
```

it won't let me do that, compilation will fail.

I'll have to convert it to bool explicitly:

```
var a=33;
if(a!=0)
   // do something
```

It's a great thing for preventing tiny nasty bugs that are hard to find, like accidental assigning with `=` instead of `==`. Is it possible to make TS work this way too? Thank you.