# Typescript should not allow functions without brackets in a condition

Tags: typescript

The following code should throw a compile error. 99.9% of the times this is not the behaviour you want. 
Is there any way to make typescript throw a compile error for this?

```
function test() {
    return false;
}
if (test) {//what you meant to do was test(), TS should report an error here
    console.log("This should be stopped by typescript");
}
```

Comment: I beg to disagree. It's *very* common to check if a function is defined or not.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122702/how-to-prevent-implicit-conversion-to-bool-in-conditions - also raised [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1296). Suggestion from the TS team is to use a custom linting rule

Comment: @Rob: Thanks, do you know if such a lint rule exists?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (test as Boolean)
```

Now the compilation will fail with

> Type '() => void' cannot be converted to type 'Boolean'.

Comment: Might as well do: If (test === true)

Comment: But the programmer still has to write the `as` [or the bracket](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) expression explicitly. In this case it should read `if (test as Function && test())`. If the programmer forgets to explicitly write this it would still be an error trap.